# Using Functions on cells in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a function using IP addresses in a DataFrame. The idea is to look at all the IP's in the df['IP'] column and return the country to the df['Country'] column.

```
import geoip
import pandas as pd

def country_lookup(IP):
    return geoip.country(IP)

df = pd.DataFrame({'IP':['99.11.100.60','99.16.198.20','99.88.55.4'],
'Country':['na','na','na']})

Attempted Solution 1
df['Country'] = df['IP'].apply(country_lookup)  

Attempted Solution 2
for i in df['IP']:
    df['Country'] = country_lookup(i)
```

Both attempts returned same country code for all rows.

Thanks for the help I am new to programming and have not been able to find a solution.

Comment: For the future, please do not tag things as languages that they are not. This is clearly Python and not R.

Comment: you may want to check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211314/pandas-fastest-way-to-resolve-ip-to-country)

Answer (score 1):

Try with Lambda

```
df['Country'] = df['IP'].apply(lambda x: country_lookup(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it is working for my example but I am running into an error in my program. IndexError: tuple index out of range any suggestion on what to look at. When printing my dataframe everything looks correct.

Comment: I would need the entire dataframe to check the problem. with the error only it's pretty hard to tell

Comment: I may have figured this one out. I am reading from an sql database and I don't have an index column.